# How do I know the macports package name for a command?

Tags: macports

A script I need to run uses `tempfile`, but I don't have that on my Mac. I do use Macports. How can I find out which Macports package I need to install to get `tempfile`?

`tempfile` is a shell command used in scripting. It's an ELF binary on my Linux box and belongs to the `debianutils` package, as shown by `dpkg -S /bin/tempfile`. I Installed the Macports debianutils package and now have `tempfile`.

Just wondering how I'll figure this out if I don't have a Linux box handy...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a program and not development. Try on AskDifferent or SuperUser

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456982/find-a-macports-package-given-a-file-name

Answer (score 1):

Is tempfile a Python library? If so, you should be able to install it with `pip` if you have it.

On another note, you should probably switch to Homebrew as your package manager.

Comment: I don't find it helpful when you tell me to switch package managers without telling me how this would solve my current problem.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see your edited post where you said it's a binary. I read a bit and apparently tempfile is depracated in favour of mktemp, which you should have by default on your mac (I seem to have it and don't recall installing it)

Comment: Thanks. You're right, I do have `/usr/bin/mktemp` (so it was shipped with Apple's software). It is probably a better solution than tempfile, but I need this script to work without changes.

Comment: Hmm, if the syntax of mktemp and tempfile is the same, maybe just do a soft link from `usr/bin/tempfile` to `/usr/bin/mktemp`. No idea if it won't break your script though.

Comment: Could be. I got `tempfile`, so I am good here. I'd just be interested on how to deal with this problem in general. How do I find out what package I need to install to get a certain binary?

Comment: If you have a shell script it will have to be altered to run on different OSs. If they were all Unix like OSX then you might be OK but Linux is non standard :)

Comment: On Linux I can install and use `apt-file` but Macports doesn't seem to have that.