# Find a macports package given a file name

Tags: macports

How can one find out the name of the port given a file name, more concretely an executable?

Macport website does not seem to help as you can only search by title and little more.

Thanks!

Comment: Which executable in particular are you looking for? Maybe I have it installed or know the port that contains it.

Comment: None in concrete... I found the one I was looking for eventually but this is the third time that I needed to know how to and I though should find out.

Comment: related (the reverse): [Listing all files installed by some MacPorts package](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/47547/6786)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Unfortunately MacPorts currently (2.3.1) only supports that if you have the port installed, i.e. if you want to find out which port installed a file on your system. In this case, you can use `port provides </full/path/to/filename>`.

If you are looking for a port to install using an executable name, you're out of luck – MacPorts doesn't have the required databases to do that.

What I usually do instead is search for the file in a Linux distribution, e.g. using `apt-file search <filename>` on Debian. Given the Debian package name, I search for a similar MacPorts port.

**Update 2022-11-30:** MacPorts now has a web application available at https://ports.macports.org/search/, which can do this. Use the "File installed" search box in the left sidebar.

Note the documented limitations of this search:

> The application fetches data for installed files from the buildbot
> every time a port is built. The application does not have information
> about the ports which have never been built since its inception.
>
> This filter searches for the files in the most recent successful build
> of a port, if available in application database.

Comment: Sort of complementary information: there exists a program called `pkgutil` (at `/usr/sbin/pkgutil`) that prints information about files of macOS's own installed packages. `pkgutil` could possibly be used to find out how a file was installed. More details: https://superuser.com/a/891702/199930