# Inspect and get binary from ELF file on macOS

Tags: macos, binary, elf, binutils, otool

I have a ELF file and I want to get a `hex` or `bin` file of my code from it. In the terminal, if a do a `file main`, which is my file, it shows:

```
main: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, UCB RISC-V, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

As I learned, `objdump` on macOS is not working and with `otool -l main` I get the following error:

```
llvm-objdump: 'main': Object is not a Mach-O file type.
```

The ELF file was created using the command:

```
riscv-none-gcc/8.2.0-2.1-20190425-1021/bin/riscv-none-embed-gcc --specs=nosys.specs main.c -o main
```

So is there a way to do it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Instead of otool try syntax compatible jtool written by Jonathan Levin, it has ELF support and runs on macOS.

Comment: @Kamil.S Thanks, i tried `jtool/jtool -l main` but that threw me `Unable to recognize this file - 464C457F`

Answer (score 13):

For creating ["raw binary files"](https://software-dl.ti.com/ccs/esd/documents/sdto_cgt_an_introduction_to_binary_files.html)
the program [`objcopy`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.36/binutils.html#objcopy)
can be used, as described [here](http://cs107e.github.io/guides/binutils/#objcopy):

```sh
objcopy -O binary foo.elf foo.bin
```

The program `objcopy` is part of the [MacPorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts)
package [`x86_64-elf-binutils`](https://ports.macports.org/port/x86_64-elf-binutils/summary),
and can be used as follows:

```sh
/opt/local/bin/x86_64-elf-objcopy -O binary foo.elf foo.bin
```

where `foo.elf` is an ELF file compiled on (or cross-compiled for) an x86_64
Linux. The MacPorts package `x86_64-elf-binutils` can be installed as follows:

```sh
port install x86_64-elf-binutils
```

The program `objcopy` is part of [`binutils`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Binutils).
For Mach-O, it can be installed on macOS via the [package `binutils`](https://ports.macports.org/port/binutils/summary)
of [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org), as follows:

```sh
port install binutils
```

The MacPorts `binutils` package installs `gobjcopy`.

Versions of `binutils` on macOS for cross-development for other target systems,
too, are [available](https://ports.macports.org/?search=binutils&search_by=name)
via MacPorts.

This post is motivated also by [MacOSX: which dynamic libraries linked by binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45464584/1959808),
and is intended to be also informational.

Executables can be:

- [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) on Linux
- [Mach-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) on macOS

### `ldd`

[`ldd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) is a script in Linux
that wraps `ld`. It is described as

> print shared object dependencies

The GNU `ld` is unavailable on macOS. More fundamentally, that `ldd` calls `ld`
means that its operation is non-static, in contrast to tools like `readelf`,
`objdump`, and `nm`.

In that sense, even if certain information is obtainable using tools other
than `ldd`, the results are not equivalent, because the other tools do not
attempt to load the binary. Moreover, attempting to load a binary requires
being on a Linux, so `ldd` is
genuinely a Linux tool that cannot be emulated exactly by a program on macOS.
A [relevant description](https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/crossgcc/2008-09/msg00061.html).
There does exist a pure-Python implementation that approximates `ldd` *without*
loading binaries the way that `ld` does: [`lddcollect`](https://github.com/Kirill888/lddcollect).
Using `lddcollect` is possible on a Linux system, where the required libraries
are present.

One reason to not use `ldd` is security: inspecting executables without
executing them.

[`ldd` is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ldd_(Unix)) an initialism for
"List Dynamic Dependencies".

`ldd` appears to be a bash script that is part of [`glibc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library), with source code at:
https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=elf/ldd.bash.in;h=ba736464ac5e4a9390b1b6a39595035238250232;hb=271ec55d0ae795f03d92e3aa61bff69a31a19e3a

- Relevant: [What is the difference between ldd and objdump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524820/what-is-the-difference-between-ldd-and-objdump)
- Relevant: [cross compiler ldd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150000/cross-compiler-ldd)

### `objdump`

[`objdump`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objdump) shows information about
object files, and can disassemble them. It is part of [`binutils`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Binutils).

Programs that are called `objdump` on macOS:

- `/opt/local/bin/gobjdump` by the MacPorts package `binutils`
- `/usr/bin/objdump` by macOS (part of package `com.apple.pkg.Essentials`),
  which is described as the

  > llvm object file dumper

The manual of `ldd` suggests calling `objdump` as an alternative, as follows:

```sh
objdump -p /path/to/program | grep NEEDED
```

Relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/206547/how-can-i-install-objdump-on-mac-os-x

### `readelf`

[`readelf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readelf) displays information about
ELF files by reading them (static, not loading them). It is part of `binutils`.
It does *not* disassemble files, like `objdump` can.

Variants available on macOS:

- `/opt/local/bin/greadelf` from the MacPorts package `binutils`
- `/opt/local/bin/elftc-readelf` from the MacPorts package `elftoolchain`

Example usage:

```sh
readelf -s elf_file
```

### `nm`

- `/usr/bin/nm` by macOS (part of package `com.apple.pkg.Essentials`)
- `/opt/local/bin/nm` by the MacPorts package `cctools`,
  which is a symbolic link: `/opt/local/bin/nm -> llvm-nm-mp-10`
- `/opt/local/bin/nm-classic` by the MacPorts package `cctools`
- `/opt/local/bin/elftc-nm` by the MacPorts package `elftoolchain`
- `/opt/local/bin/gnm` by the MacPorts package `binutils`

Apparently, both `/usr/bin/nm` and `/opt/local/bin/nm` are versions of the

> llvm symbol table dumper
> and do work with ELF files.

### `otool` (and variants)

`otool` is the the disassembler for MacOS's Mach-O format.

Variants of `otool` available on macOS:

- `/usr/bin/otool` by macOS (part of package `com.apple.pkg.Essentials`)
- `/opt/local/bin/otool` by the MacPorts package `cctools`,
  which links to `/opt/local/bin/llvm-otool` by the MacPorts package `cctools`,
  which is described as:

  > the otool-compatible command line parser for llvm-objdump
- `/opt/local/bin/otool-classic` by the MacPorts package `cctools`

More details:

```sh
> which -a otool
/opt/local/bin/otool
/usr/bin/otool
> ls -lsa /opt/local/bin/otool
... /opt/local/bin/otool -> llvm-otool
> port provides /opt/local/bin/otool
/opt/local/bin/otool is provided by: cctools
> which -a llvm-otool
/opt/local/bin/llvm-otool
> port provides /opt/local/bin/llvm-otool
/opt/local/bin/llvm-otool is provided by: cctools
> ls -lsa /usr/bin/otool
... /usr/bin/otool
> pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/otool
volume: /
path: /usr/bin/otool

pkgid: com.apple.pkg.Essentials
...
```

The MacPorts package `cctools` installs also `/opt/local/bin/otool-classic`,
which, as said in its documentation, is obsolete.

### `elfdump`

`elfdump` is available on macOS via the MacPorts package `elftoolchain`,
and installed as the binary `/opt/local/bin/elftc-elfdump`.

### `strings`

The program [`strings`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strings_(Unix)) can be
useful for inspecting the symbols contained in an ELF file. It is a more
general tool, not designed specifically for ELF files, but usable nonetheless.

Variants of `strings` on macOS:

- `/usr/bin/strings` by macOS (part of package `com.apple.pkg.Essentials`)
- `/opt/local/bin/strings` from the MacPorts package `cctools`
- `/opt/local/bin/elftc-strings` from the MacPorts package `elftoolchain`
- `/opt/local/bin/gstrings` from the MacPorts package `binutils`

Example usage (piping to [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)):

```sh
strings some_elf_file | ag GLIBC
```

`elftc-strings` appears to have fewer options and give fewer results than
the other `strings` implementations (which differ with each other, but seem
to print similar results).

### `elftoolchain`

Available via MacPorts, [`elftoolchain`](http://elftoolchain.sourceforge.net)
is a BSD-licensed library of tools like those in `binutils`. Tools from that
collection that are relevant to analyzing ELF files:

- `/opt/local/bin/elftc-elfdump`
- `/opt/local/bin/elftc-nm`
- `/opt/local/bin/elftc-readelf`
- `/opt/local/bin/elftc-strings`

There are also [plans](https://sourceforge.net/p/elftoolchain/wiki/Home/) for
implementing `objdump`.

### Confirming that a binary is from MacPorts

To find out whether a given file is part of MacPorts:

```sh
> port provides /opt/local/bin/otool
/opt/local/bin/otool is provided by: cctools
```

Discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25460320/1959808).

### Confirming that a binary is from macOS

Also [useful](https://superuser.com/a/891702/199930) for finding out how each
of the tools discussed above was installed is `pkgutil`:

```
pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/objdump
```

This can be useful to confirm that a binary was part of macOS itself, and not
installed by other means.

### Confirming that an executable is an ELF

This text was motivated when I wanted to analyze an executable with the
following details:

```
> file filename
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=..., for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

As for other tools, there are multiple options for `file` on macOS:

- `/usr/bin/file` by macOS (part of package `com.apple.pkg.Essentials`)
- `/opt/local/bin/file` by the MacPorts package `file`

### Other tools

Apparently, on some operating systems there are also [`elftools`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#Tools) available.

For analyzing files for specific architectures, there are MacPorts packages
like `arm-elf-binutils`.

### DWARF

There is also [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) and `dwarftool`,
as well as `dwarfdump` (part of XCode).

### Miscellanea

- `binutils` can analyze Mach-O on Linux:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8714142/1959808
- [`darling`](https://github.com/darlinghq/darling) can be used on Linux to run
  macOS software (Mach-O, `dyld`), it is analogous to `wine`

Comment: What an **AMAZING** answer! I'm going to bookmark it actually. Some are especially useful like checking if they're part of macOS by default. This is very useful to me! Have a +1! It might be useful to point out though that with Apple silicon chip you cannot compile ELF - at least to my knowledge. As well Apple makes it very hard nowadays to compile 32-bit binaries (incredibly annoying bu there it is). Anyway great answer - thanks!